Is it possible to run TFTP from Apache server?
Today we run Open TFTP and Apache as two different applications on a Windows 11 Pro, x64-bit machine. We start them separately. The Apache we run is Apache Haus 2.4.46. Is there a way to run TFTP from Apache instead so that we only have to use the Apache server? Is there a TFTP plugin one can add/enable on Apache available?

The Apache you run appears to be apache httpd (the Apache foundation coordinate the development of a LOT of different projects). httpd serves http. It does not serve tftp.

Thanks. Yes i thought so. It will have to run as a standalone server alongside Apache,
